# C# & WinUI 3 - Boggling Binding is Breaking my Brain

Tags: c#, binding, winui-3

I am trying to figure out binding yet again. I started a WinUI 3 template with a main page and a blank page. This sample app is to try and figure out binding. There seems to be so much conflicting info on this.

This is BlankPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="app1Binding.Views.BlankPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:app1Binding.ViewModels">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="button1" 
                    Content="press" 
                    Click="button1_Click" 
                    Width="200" Height="75" Margin="40"/>
            <TextBox Background="{x:Bind StatusBarColor}" Text="HELLO" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is BlankPage.xaml.cs

```
<pre lang="C#">using app1Binding.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace app1Binding.Views;

public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
{
    public BlankViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public BlankPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<BlankViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new BlankViewModel();
    }

    private SolidColorBrush statusBarColor;
    public SolidColorBrush StatusBarColor
    {
        get => statusBarColor;
        set => statusBarColor = value;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StatusBarColor = new SolidColorBrush(Microsoft.UI.Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

and this is BlankViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace app1Binding.ViewModels;

public class BlankViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    private SolidColorBrush statusBarColor;

    public SolidColorBrush StatusBarColor
    {
        get
        {
            return statusBarColor;
        }
        set
        {
            statusBarColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusBarColor));
        }
    }

    public BlankViewModel()
    {
        StatusBarColor = new SolidColorBrush(Microsoft.UI.Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

I believe that I am supposed to use 'x:Bind' and not 'Binding' in this case. If you recreate this app, you just need to click on Blank on the left side once it has started running. The intent is that the HELLO TextBox should be red at the start and change to green once 'PRESS' is clicked. With 'x:Bind' it stays white the whole time. If I use 'Binding' instead it is red at the start but does not change with one or more 'PRESS'es. Oddly enough, if I 'PRESS' and then change the 'Binding' to 'x:Bind' while running, the button actually changes to green?? It is like the values may have changed but the UI is just not updating??? I was unaware of how 'OnPropertyChanged (nameof(StatusBarColor))' was used but after reading a bit on it I left it in. Any idea on what I am missing?? Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimal working sample from your code:

**BlankViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace app1Binding.ViewModels;

// This class needs to be "partial"
// for the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm's source generator.
public partial class BlankViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    // A "StatusBarColor" will be generated.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private SolidColorBrush _statusBarColor = new(Colors.Red);

    // A "UpdateStatusBarColorCommand" will be generated.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void UpdateStatusBarColor()
    {
        StatusBarColor = new(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

**BlankPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using app1Binding.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace app1Binding.Views;

public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
{
    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BlankViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**BlankPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="app1Binding.Views.BlankPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:app1Binding.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.UpdateStatusBarColorCommand}"
            Content="press" />
        <TextBox
            Background="{x:Bind ViewModel.StatusBarColor, Mode=OneWay}"
            Text="HELLO" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

**Notes:**

- It is recommended to use `x:Bind` instead of `Binding` for better performance. But have in mind that `x:Bind` needs to resolve the target path in compile time whereas `Binding` does in runtime.
- `x:Bind` won't compile just by setting a ViewModel in the `DataContext`. That's why I'm including `ViewModel` in the binding path.
- `x:Bind` is `OneTime` by default. If the value might change, you need to set `OneWay` or `TwoWay`.
- Let the **CommunitToolkit.Mvvm** generate code for you and keep your code clean.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this Andrew. I input your code and got the following errors.   
1.)  Error CS0616 'RelayCommand' is not an attribute class ...\BlankViewModel.cs 17
2.)  Error XLS0432 The property 'UpdateStatusBarColorCommand' was not found in type 'BlankViewModel'. ...\BlankPage.xaml 13 
3.) Error  IDE1100    Error reading (& finding) content of ...app1Binding.AssemblyInfo.cs...  Then updated two Nugets and it worked. I was having issues with CTK.MVVM previously and I forgot why I did not update previously. Thanks again.

Comment: There's an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/67123#issuecomment-1489157031) with the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** v8.1. You should use v8.0 for the moment.

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks! I tried to upvote but I did not have enough points yet.

Comment: Great! Then mark it as accepted so we can close this question wen you can.